Win Form loaded from ComboCloseUp event of a far point spread combobox doesnt fire events on first click of the button
I'm using far point spread in my window application and one of its cell is of type combo box.
On combocloseup event, it is supposed to launch custom form with 2 buttons on it.
The form launches, however the button click events wont trigger on first click of the button.
This is not the case with key events. If I launch the form and hit enter, the focus on load is on cancel button and the form closes as per cancel button logic
I ran spy++, found out that the first click is sending the message WM_MOUSEACTIVATE
and second click is sending the message WM_CLOSE and destroy etc.
The form works fine when loaded from combo box that are present outside the spread.
Tried Form.Activate(), form.bringtofront() spy++ tool debugging.
Launched the form from combobox outside the spread where it works fine on first clicks.
